# How to map two arrays in my case

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to map two arrays and create a brand new array in my codes

I have something like

```
var array1 =[
   {'name':'John'
    'id': '1'},
   {'name':'Ted'
    'id': '2'},
   {'name':'KK'
    'id': '3'}
];
var array2 =[1, 2]; 

var info = [];    

for (var i = 0; i <array2.length; i++){
    var id = array2[i];
    var p = array1.filter(function(person){
          return id === person.id
     })

     info.push(p)
}
```

I want my `info` array contains John and Ted like

```
[ 
   {'name':'John'
    'id': '1'},
   {'name':'Ted'
    'id': '2'}
]
```

but instead, I got

```
[ 
   [ 
       {'name':'John'
       'id': '1'}
   ],
   [
      {'name':'Ted'
      'id': '2'}
   ]
]
```

I am not sure what I do wrong. Is there anyway I can improve my code to be more sufficient? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should fix the fancy quotes

Comment: Your code is inside-out. Loop over `array2` within the `filter`, or better use `indexOf` or `some`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `push` but `concat`, because the `p` you get from `filter` is already an array. So change:

```
info.push(p)
```

to:

```
info = info.concat(p)
```

Secondly, you are comparing strings with numbers, so change:

```
var array2 = [1, 2];
```

to:

```
var array2 = ['1', '2'];
```

or, change the `id` values to numbers. The following snippet does that, and also makes the code more concise with the use of `Array.prototype.indexOf`:

```js
var array1 =[
   {'name':'John', 'id': 1},
   {'name':'Ted',  'id': 2},
   {'name':'KK',   'id': 3}
];
var array2 = [1, 2];
var info = array1.filter(function (person) {
    return array2.indexOf(person.id) !== -1;
});   
console.log(info);
```

Comment: Thanks but concat doesn't seem to do it. The info become empty array after i changed it to concat +1 tho

Comment: Change `return id === person.id` to `return id == person.id`

Comment: @abM still doesn't work

Comment: @FlyingCat, did you check the snippet? It works for me... or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: that does it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're pushing `p`, but not each person object to the `info` array. Additionally, you've syntax errors. Some other coding errors are noted in @trincot answer.

```
var array1 =[
   {name: 'John', id: 1},
   {name: 'Ted', id: 2},
   {name: 'KK', id: 3}
], array2 = [1, 2]; 

var info = [];  
for (var i = 0, b = array2.length; i < b; i++) {
    var id = array2[i];
    array1.filter(function(person) {
        if(id === person.id) {
            info.push(person);
            return true; // breaks the filter
        }
    });
}
```